# Instantiate XCTestCase subclass multiple times in a test run

Tags: xctest

I have an `XCTestCase` subclass `EndpointIntegrationTests` that contains integration tests that exercise the client application's endpoints against the backend.

We have a number of testing backend environments. They share the same databases, so the tests in `EndpointIntegrationTests` should work equally well on all of the backends.

I'd like to be able to instantiate multiple instance of `EndpointIntegrationTests` in a test run, initialising each (or configuring after initialisation) with the specific backend it should test. I'd then instantiate the suite once for each backend, so that all tests are run against all backends. Perhaps a bit like this…

```
func addTestCaseInstances() {
  for environment in ["SIT01", "SIT02", "NFT"] {
    let testCase = EndpointIntegrationTests(environment: environment)
    addTestCaseInstance(testCase)
  }
}
```

Is there a mechanism in XCTest to allow this? I've only ever seen `XCTestCase` subclasses be automatically instantiated by the test harness. The harness only instantiates each subclass once.

Thanks.